# Transform all elements positionally below 0 into 0 in a matrix (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, linear-algebra

This is a matrix :

```
matrix = [[1, 1, 1, 0], 
          [0, 5, 0, 1], 
          [2, 1, 3, 10]]
```

I want to change all the element *positionally* below 0 into 0 (on the same column).

The resulting matrix will be :

```
matrix = [[1, 1, 1, 0], 
          [0, 5, 0, 0], 
          [0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

I tried this so far. The return is empty

```python
import numpy as np
def transform(matrix):
    newmatrix = np.asarray(matrix)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    for j in range(0,len(matrix[0])-1):
        while i < int(len(matrix))-1 and j < int(len(matrix[0]))-1:
            if newmatrix[i][j] == 0:
                np.put(newmatrix,newmatrix[i+1][j], 0 )
        i +=1
    return print (newmatrix)
```

Comment: "I want to change all the element below 0 into 0 (on the same line)." But all elements are above 0. So why should matrix change?

Comment: Should it be: `matrix = [[1, 1, 1, 0],  [0, 5, 0,- 1], [-2, 1, -3, -10]]`?

Comment: in fact i need to multiply all the numbers below 0 in the column by 0

Comment: @FritzFABO I've edited your question to what I think it should be. can you have a look?

Comment: Why are you returning `print()`? It is always `None`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Method 1 (Original)

```
import numpy as np
def transform(matrix):
    mat = np.asarray(matrix)
    mat[np.logical_not(np.not_equal(mat, 0).cumprod(axis=0))] = 0
    # Alternatively:
    # mat[~(mat != 0).cumprod(axis=0, dtype=np.bool)] = 0
    # or,
    # mat[~((mat != 0).cumprod(axis=0, dtype=np.bool))] = 0
    return mat
```

Then with your sample data, I get the following `mat`:

```
In [195]: matrix = [[1, 1, 1, 0], 
     ...:           [0, 5, 0, 1], 
     ...:           [2, 1, 3, 10]]

In [196]: transform(matrix)
Out[196]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 5, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

## Method 2 (further optimized)

```
def transform2(matrix):
    mat = np.asarray(matrix)
    mat *= (mat != 0).cumprod(axis=0, dtype=np.bool)
    return mat
```

## Method 3 (even more optimized)

```
def transform3(matrix):
    mat = np.asarray(matrix)
    mat *= mat.cumprod(axis=0, dtype=np.bool)
    return mat
```

## Explanation

Let's look at the main statement (in Method 1):

```
mat[np.logical_not(np.not_equal(mat, 0).cumprod(axis=0))] = 0
```

We can split it into several "elementary" operations:

1. Create a boolean mask containing `False` (numerically `0`) where elements of `mat` are `0` and `True` (numerically `1`) where they are non-zero:

   ```
   mask1 = np.not_equal(mat, 0)
   ```
2. Using the fact that numerically `False` is 0, use [`cumprod()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.cumprod.html) function (a good explanation can be found here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumprod.html)

   ```
   mask2 = mask1.cumprod(axis=0)
   ```

   Since `1*1==1` and `0*0` or `0*1` is `0`, all elements of this "mask" will be either `0` or `1`. They will be `0` only in locations for which `mask1` is zero *and below* (!) because of the "cumulative nature" of the product *along the columns* (hence `axis=0`).
3. Now, we want set those elements of `mat` that correspond to `0` in `mask2` to `0`. To do this we create a boolean mask that is `True` where `mask2` is `0` and `False` elsewhere. This can be easily achieved by applying logical (or binary) NOT to `mask2`:

   ```
   mask3 = np.logical_not(mask2)
   ```

   Using "logical" NOT here creates a boolean array thus we avoid explicit type conversion.
4. Finally we use [Boolean Indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) to select those elements of `mat` that need to be set to `0` and set them to `0`:

   ```
   mat[mask3] = 0
   ```

---

### OPTIONAL OPTIMIZATION

If you think of it, we can get rid of steps 3 and 4 if we do the following:

```
mask2 = mask1.cumprod(axis=0, dtype=np.bool) #convert result to boolean type 
mat *= mask2 # combined step 3&4
```

See "Method 2" section above for a complete implementation.

### PERFORMANCE

There have been several additional answers that use `numpy.ufunc.accumulate()`. Fundamentally, all these methods revolve around the idea that `0` is a "special" value in the sense that `0*anything==0` or, in the case of @DSM's answer, that `False=0<True=0` AND letting `numpy` perform "cumulative" operation on arrays.

There are some variations in performance but most are minimal except for my method #1 that is slower than other methods.

Here are some timing tests for more functions. NOTE: in order to perform tests correctly, we need to use large arrays. Small array tests will be measuring overhead, cashing, etc.

```
In [1]: import sys
    ...: import numpy as np
    ...: 

In [2]: print(sys.version)
    ...: 
3.6.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul 20 2017, 13:14:59) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]

In [3]: print(np.__version__)
    ...: 
1.12.1

In [4]: # Method 1 (Original)
    ...: def transform1(matrix):
    ...:     mat = np.asarray(matrix)
    ...:     mat[np.logical_not(np.not_equal(mat, 0).cumprod(axis=0))] = 0
    ...:     return mat
    ...: 

In [5]: # Method 2:
    ...: def transform2(matrix):
    ...:     mat = np.asarray(matrix)
    ...:     mat *= (mat != 0).cumprod(axis=0, dtype=np.bool)
    ...:     return mat
    ...: 

In [6]: # @DSM method:
    ...: def transform_DSM(matrix):
    ...:     mat = np.asarray(matrix)
    ...:     mat *= np.minimum.accumulate(mat != 0)
    ...:     return mat
    ...: 

In [7]: # @DanielF method:
    ...: def transform_DanielF(matrix):
    ...:     mat = np.asarray(matrix)
    ...:     mat[~np.logical_and.accumulate(mat, axis = 0)] = 0
    ...:     return mat
    ...: 

In [8]: # Optimized @DanielF method:
    ...: def transform_DanielF_optimized(matrix):
    ...:     mat = np.asarray(matrix)
    ...:     mat *= np.logical_and.accumulate(mat, dtype=np.bool)
    ...:     return mat
    ...: 

In [9]: matrix = np.random.randint(0, 20000, (20000, 20000))

In [10]: %timeit -n1 transform1(matrix)
22.1 s ± 241 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [11]: %timeit -n1 transform2(matrix)
9.29 s ± 185 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [12]: %timeit -n1 transform3(matrix)
9.23 s ± 180 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [13]: %timeit -n1 transform_DSM(matrix)
9.24 s ± 195 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [14]: %timeit -n1 transform_DanielF(matrix)
10.3 s ± 219 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [15]: %timeit -n1 transform_DanielF_optimized(matrix)
9.27 s ± 187 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

My initial solution (Method 1) is slowest while other methods are much faster. @DanielF original method is somewhat slower due to use of boolean indexing (but the optimized variant is as fast as other optimized methods).

Comment: @kmario23 Not really: `binary_not` is applied to the end-result of `not_equal().cumprod()`

Comment: @kmario23 I rewrote main statement in a more explicit way.

Comment: Or more put a paranthesis around it: `mat[~((mat != 0).cumprod(axis=0).astype(np.bool))] = 0` to avoid confusion. Good solution, btw :)

Comment: "mat[~((mat != 0).cumprod(axis=0, dtype=np.bool))] = 0" Where can I find documentation to understand this line ?

Comment: @FritzFABO Fundamentally `~` is `binary_not()` but can be used in place of  `logical_not()` when argument is a boolean type - so read https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.logical_not.html. `(mat!=0)` is the same as `not_equal()`  - so see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.not_equal.html. For `cumprod()` - see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.cumprod.html

Comment: @FritzFABO I have added 1) detailed explanation AND 2) a further simplified/optimized algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple (though not optimised) algorithm:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

m = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 0], 
              [0, 5, 0, 1], 
              [2, 1, 3, 10]])

@jit(nopython=True)
def zeroer(m):
    a, b = m.shape
    for j in range(b):
        for i in range(a):
            if m[i, j] == 0:
                m[i:, j] = 0
                break
    return m

zeroer(m)

# [[1 1 1 0]
#  [0 5 0 0]
#  [0 1 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

One variant of the `cumprod` approach is to use a cumulative minimum (or maximum).  I prefer this slightly because you can use it to avoid any arithmetic operations beyond comparison, if you wanted, although it's hard to get worked up about it:

```
In [37]:  m
Out[37]: 
array([[ 1,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  5,  0,  1],
       [ 2,  1,  3, 10]])

In [38]: m * np.minimum.accumulate(m != 0)
Out[38]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 5, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0]])

In [39]: np.where(np.minimum.accumulate(m != 0), m, 0)
Out[39]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 5, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: `m * np.minimum.accumulate(m, dtype=np.bool)` works as well.

Answer (score 1):

A more optimized version of @AGNGazer solution using `np.logical_and.accumulate` and implicit boolean casting of integers (which doesn't require a lot of multiplication)

```
def transform(matrix):
    mat = np.asarray(matrix)
    mat[~np.logical_and.accumulate(mat, axis = 0)] = 0
    return mat

transform(m)
Out:
array([[1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 5, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Timings:

```
%timeit transform2(m) # AGN's solution
The slowest run took 44.73 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.93 µs per loop

%timeit transform(m)
The slowest run took 9.00 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.99 µs per loop

m = np.random.randint(0,5,(100,100))

%timeit transform(m)
The slowest run took 6.03 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 43.9 µs per loop

%timeit transform2(m)
The slowest run took 4.09 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 50.4 µs per loop
```

Looks to be about a 15% speedup.

Comment: I added a timing comparison section to my answer and it shows that, as published, your method is slower than all other methods except for my Method 1 which is slowest of `numpy`-based methods.